# how can I install pspell in php5/windows

Tags: php, apache, windows-7, pspell

I have installed pspell according to

http://pritomkumar.blogspot.com/2013/04/enabling-pspell-for-php-in-xampp-on.html

but when trying to restart xampp apache shows me the error:

`PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'php_pspell.dll'`

Comment: did you find a way to fix it?